# The value of a variable for creating dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am not sure if it's possible. But I am looking for a function that dynamically evaluates the value of a variable and pastes it in place of the variable itself.

Scenario:

```
resources: resourcesSource,
```

I have the above line in one of my plugins declaration. The variable **resourcesSource** contains the required jSon string. Now what I want is something like this:

```
resources: evaluate(resourcesSource),
```

After this the javascript should take it as:

```
resources: [{'name': 'Adil Malik','id': '217_resid'},{'name': 'Adam Jones','id': '433_resid'},{'name': 'help team','id': '2056_resid'},]
```

instead of putting the variable there like this:

```
resources: resourcesSource,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in jQuery `$.parseJSON()` function to do that.  Although if `resourcesSource` is already a JSON object, there is no need as it will be accessible through `resources`.

```
resources: $.parseJSON(resourcesSource),
...
```

---

Reference - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

> **Description:**
>   Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.

Comment: No, it doesn't work either. parseJSON returns javascript object. I already have a javascript object i.e. resourcesSource. I don't want a JSon object. I just want the value of resourcesSource to be pasted in place of the variable. So, the javascript sees the value not the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a JSON object back into a string variable, you'll have to use an external plugin/function to do this for you.

You can take a look at this version - [jQuery.stringify() utility](https://gist.github.com/754454/)

Using it you can easily revert JSON objects back to their string representations.

One more thing to note is that you had a trailing comma after the last element in the object.

```
[
 {'name': 'Adil Malik','id': '217_resid'},  
 {'name': 'Adam Jones','id': '433_resid'},  
 {'name': 'help team','id': '2056_resid'}
]
```

Note the removal of the trailing comma after the 3rd element.

Running the `jQuery.stringify(a);` function will return a string representation of that object -

> "[{"name":"Adil Malik","id":"217_resid"},{"name":"Adam
>   Jones","id":"433_resid"},{"name":"help team","id":"2056_resid"}]"

Comment: Note that if you want to access properties of that variable once you have converted it back into its string form, you'll have to parse it again into an object....